# Bad keyboard bouncing with Dell keyboard

Tags: debian, keyboard

I've tried several Dell keyboards with the Pi, and all the ones I've tried (they're definitely not faulty, work fine elsewhere) "bounce" horribly - that is every so often it doesn't seem to detect I've released a key and will thus act like the key is being held down until another is pressed. This gets rather annoying very quickly!

A Logitech keyboard I had lying around works fine, so it's not a problem with the Pi (both Pis I have display the same behaviour.)

Is this a known problem and if so is it solvable (without changing the keyboard?)

Currently running the default Debian squeeze distribution.

Comment: Sounds like bad keyboard modules. Is this within xorg?

Comment: @Jivings Both in and outside of x.org - sometimes the problem occurs when logging into the terminal which is *really* annoying!

Comment: ...That is weird. +1

Comment: Just to cover all details can you state the distro too please.

Comment: @Jivings Sure, edited to add.

Comment: Added the tags for you too.

Comment: Have you tried this on Fedora or Arch Linux?

Comment: I would try debugging using `xev`; you will have to start an xserver first.

Comment: As stated, the problem is not specific to X, so I don't see how this will help.

Comment: It will show key presses etc.

Comment: Key presses caught be X. It doesn't really help to diagnose the problem.

Comment: I am having the same problem using a cerulean wireless keyboard from Maplin.
I think that it is down to a software fault because if I run the RISC OS system on my raspberry PI there is no problem at all. This really needs someone far more skill than I to look into it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I see the same problem with a Dell keyboard, and I believe it's down to the fact that the keyboard has a built-in USB hub. This is from the [R-Pi Troubleshooting page at elinux.org](http://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting#R-Pi_does_not_respond_to_key_presses_.2F_Keyboard_randomly_repeats_key_presses):

> **R-Pi does not respond to key presses / Keyboard randomly repeats key
>   presses**
>
> This is caused by inadequate power. Use a good power supply
>   and a good power cable. Some cheap cables that work with a cell phone,
>   cannot fully power the R-Pi. Some USB devices require a lot of power:
>   most will have a label showing the voltage and mA requirements. They
>   should be 5v 100mA each max, any more than this they must be used with
>   a powered USB hub. Try unplugging every USB device except the keyboard
>   (you should also note that some keyboards have built in hubs and can
>   try to draw 150mA (Pi can only handle 100mA per USB slot without a
>   hub)). Also, use the latest software. Forum user MrEngman reported
>   some keyboard repeats and wireless hangs until upgrading to the
>   debian6-19-04-2012 kernel, which he reports stable with no problems
>   even with a low TP1-TP2 voltage of 4.65 - 4.68 volts.

Comment: I'm seeing the same with a HP keyboard - AND I have it plugged in via a powered USB hub. I may replace it with a Logitech anyway: I'd forgotten how horrible the keys felt!

Comment: I have the same problem with Microsoft wireless keyboard and I have made my own power supply as mentioned here : http://elinux.org/RPi_5V_PSU_construction but it did not solve the problem at all.